# Graph of the output Vo for a given Vi in a diode circuit explanation

Tags: diodes, graph

We have the following diode circuit:

[image: circuit]

We have found when the diode is on and off.

[image: on-off table]

I perfectly understand this.

Now the teacher gave an extra question that I don't understand. What is the output Vo (represented in a graph) when we have an input of

a) \$V_i = 100 sin(wt)\$

b) \$V_i = 150 sin(wt)\$

She then drew the correct graphs. I have attached them here, respectively a and b:

[image: graph a]
[image: graph b]

I see the graphs, but I don't understand them. What is their explanation, how are they working?

Comment: You didnt answer what I asked there,I asked that I wanted the graphs explained,not this http://i.stack.imgur.com/3EnOf.jpg

Comment: Actually I *was* explaining the graphs. But still, if you did not like it, you could have added a comment with request for more details.

Comment: Then can you do a slightly more detailed explanation of vo and Vi for the two graphs?

Comment: In the original question I mean

Comment: are u searching for complete digestive answers ? @user3543012